# why is array updating so slow?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

first i write filter function in reducer after i call api, it's quite difficult for me but i still solve it without using async, so maybe the fault is not in the api call part
i have reset the state and return it, i don't see any problem in this part except it doesn't update immediately to the initicalState, i don't understand where i am going wrong or how to fix it

```
const initialState = {
    users: [],
    newUsers: []
}

export const Users = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let { user, email, password } = action
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.CREATE_USER:
            // call API - POST
            axiosUser.post('users', user)
            return state;

        case types.LOGIN_USER:
            // call api - GET USERS
            const res = axiosUser.get('users')
            res.then((res) => {
                const dataUsers = res.data
                const checkUser = dataUsers.filter(item => item.email === email && item.password === password)
                state.newUsers = checkUser
            })
            console.log(state);
            return state;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

then i call back state from redux to switch page because i can't switch page in redux
However, for some reason, I need to click a third time to get the data to be returned
i have console.log() in reducer and it seems the problem is in reducer, the data is returned as below log

```
const Login = () => {
    const newState = useSelector(state => state.Users.newUsers)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false)

    const handleSignIn = () => {
        if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
            dispatch(act_loginUser(email, password))
            console.log(newState);
            /* newState.find(function (item) {
                if (item.email === email && item.password === password) {
                    navigate('/account')
                }
                return 1
            }) */
        } else {
            setSubmit(true)
        }
    }
```

I am not good at English, please help me to solve this problem. Why does the first click still have data but it doesn't return the way I want.
I have to click a third time to get the data

```
UsersReducer.js:25 
{users: Array(0), newUsers: Array(0)}
newUsers: 
Array(1)0: {firstName: 'Phạm', lastName: 'Bình', email: 'phamgiabinh95@gmail.com', password: '98700', id: 1}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
users: []
[[Prototype]]: Object

Login.js:17 
[]
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

UsersReducer.js:25 {users: Array(0), newUsers: Array(1)}
Login.js:17 []

UsersReducer.js:25 {users: Array(0), newUsers: Array(1)}
Login.js:17 [{…}]
0: {firstName: 'Phạm', lastName: 'Bình', email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: '98700', id: 1}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot going on here, so let me break down a few problems:

- you are using an extremely outdated style of Redux here. Since 2019, you [should be using Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today), so you are probably learning from an outdated tutorial. Take a look at the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).
- you are not allowed to change `state` in Reducers the legacy style of Redux you are writing here. You would have to write "immutable" update logic. That explains in parts why your UI is not updating. Is it likely not effective for you to learn how to do this in the old style. Please just learn modern Redux, where you are allowed to change state in `createSlice` reducers.
- A reducer is never allowed to have side effect. That means you are not allowed to do api calls like your `axios` calls in a Reducer. You are doing that in a completely wrong place and there is no way of just "fixing your code". You need to write the code in a completely different way. This is, for example, covered in parts 5, 7 and 8 of the official tutorial I linked above.

I am sorry, but the gist of my answer is essentially "scrap this code, follow an up-to-date tutorial and write it from scratch".
The positive thing I can tell you is that doing what you want to do here correctly in legacy Redux would be a lot of code, and it will only be 1/4 of that code in modern Redux.